# What is the purpose of accessibility and traits?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

[image]

I would like to find out the purpose of accessibility and traits.
What is the purpose of traits's list of properties list here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Accessibility Trait allows you to choose the best description for what an element in your application does.

**accessibilityLabel**

The accessibilityLabel for an element is read by VoiceOver, and is designed to be a quick, one or two word label for what the element is. For instance, a “share” button may have an accessibilityLabel of “Share”. An “email” button may say “Email”. You get the idea. The goal is to give a brief word or two to give the user an understanding of what the element is and/or does. To implement, just go ahead and set the @property on the element:

```
[self.saveButton setAccessibilityLabel:@"Save"];
```

**accessibilityHint**

The accessibilityHint is designed to be a more lengthy description to be ready by VoiceOver. For instance, in the case of the “save” button above, you may want it to say something like “Saves the current information and returns back to the list of articles.” The @property is set similarly to the accessibilityLabel:

```
[self.saveButton setAccessibilityHint:@"Saves the current information and returns back to the list of articles."];
```

**accessibilityTraits**

You don’t have to use this for common UIKit controls, as it comes by default with the traits you’d imagine. But check out Apple’s WWDC ‘13 session on Accessibility for iOS and you’ll see how they adjusted the traits for some buttons.

AccessibilityTraits can be OR’d together to return multiple options, or just return a single one. As with the others, you can override this in a custom subclass or set it via it’s @property:

```
- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
    return UIAccessibilityTraitsButton;
}
```

Check [ThisLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5) for more information